# Visitors have to fill in their contact information twice when buying a product

Tags: magento-1.7, payment, customer-account, customer-address

Currently I get complaints about a Magento Webshop that has Multisafepay as payment provider. Client tell me they have to fill in all their information (like address etc.) twice when they buy a product. This while all this information is also in their account on the website.

I've read on the internet that more people have the same problem. Did anyone solve this? Or can anyone tell me how to solve it?

Comment: Seeing as Magento functionality only requires you to enter details once assuming the same shipping and billing address, I'm going to make an educated guess that you need to be looking at the setup and integration of your payment provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the webshop is using the entry level payment solution from Multisafepay, this requires every user to enter the details agin. You can upgrade to an other payment solution (not sure how its called) or use an other payment provider like Sisow where its not needed to enter extra information to complete the transaction.